# Targeting :first-letter of :after content pseudoelement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-element

I have a pseudoelement :after content defined in CSS.

```
div:after {
content:'This is the sentence.';
}
```

Can anyone please advise me how to target the first character of the content and change its style. Jquery is OK but I'm trying to do it with first* pseudoelement.

Comment: `:after` is not part of the DOM, and therefore cannot be manipulated further.

Comment: Would the following suffice? `div::before { content: "T" } div::after{ content: "his is text." }` Note that actual content of `div` will be *between* these pseudoelements.

Comment: Javascript cannot target pseudo elements, with or without jQuery. @JonathanSampson Only if the div didn't have any other content.

Comment: The `content` property should not be use for actual content...odd but true.

Comment: Perhaps share with the the *effect* you're attempting to achieve, and we may be able to suggest a better alternative.

Comment: if its 'ok' for you to use jQuery, why not just add the element using jQuery instead of using `:after` ?

Comment: Does your `div` actually contains text (in the DOM)?

Comment: Even if you could access the first letter, how would it's style be made different without it being some other html inside css which is really pushing the limits

Answer (score 1):

The only time `:first-letter` could possibly match the first letter of an `:after` pseudo-element is if the pseudo-element is inline, and there is no other content preceding the pseudo-element (at least in the usual LTR writing mode anyway). Furthermore, pseudo-elements cannot contain their own pseudo-elements, so you couldn't do `:after:first-letter` either.

If your `div` element has content, then you won't be able to do this using an `:after` pseudo-element. You will need to use an actual child element instead. You can easily generate one using jQuery's `.append()` method, but if you want to target `:first-letter` of *that* element, you will need to display it as either block or inline-block instead of inline:

```
$('div').append('<span class="after">This is the sentence.</span>');
```

```css
div > .after {
    display: inline-block;
}

div > .after:first-letter {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do anything like `div::after::first-letter` for the time being, but you can achieve the same end-results relatively easily by merely creating the content you wish to manipulate, and injecting it into your DOM where the `div::after` pseudo elements *would have* been placed had they been used:

```
(function () {

    var aftr = document.createElement( "div" ),
        divs = document.querySelectorAll( "div" );

    aftr.className = "after";
    aftr.textContent = "This is the sentence.";

    for ( var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) {
        divs.item(i).appendChild( aftr.cloneNode( true ) );
    }

}());
```

With these elements now in place, you can move on to styling them:

```
.after:last-child::first-letter {
    color: red;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/7gmbvewh/

One thing that immediately makes me uncomfortable is the distance between the markup and the text you want displayed within these elements. You could place the text within the markup as a data attribute:

```
<div data-after="After content">Original Content</div>
```

And then use that (if it exists) in the final loop:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) {
    var clone = aftr.cloneNode( true ),
        after = divs.item(i).dataset.after;
    if ( after ) {
        clone.textContent = after;
    }
    divs.item(i).appendChild( clone );
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/7gmbvewh/2/

Answer (score 0):

If this is a feature question, then the answer is:

> Unfortunatelly you can't target and manipulate with pseudo-elements.

But there are workarounds *(don't use `:after`, but actual elements)*, read the comments under your question.